# How to get video output or frame from VRAM

Tags: c, opengl, directx, sdl, gpu

I want to get the frame (image) that will be displayed on screen, directly from VRAM if possible in binary(RAW) format using SDL/OpenGl/DirectX or any other API.

I want to minimize latency of capturing screen then saving it to image and converting it to binary or base64.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a very good way to try and get the frame directly from VRAM. How and where the frame is laid out in memory is an implementation-dependent point, so you should use functions from your API to get that image.

With OpenGL, use [`glReadPixels`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glReadPixels.xhtml) or [PBOs](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Pixel_Buffer_Object) for async transfers.

Comment: I understand but I need to send this image over network , so to reduce latency and getting real time transfer I need to do so. As for SDL "SDL_RenderReadPixels()" function is very slow.

Comment: @hemantc: What makes you think that glReadPixels increases your latency? If anything it *reduces* the latency, because glReadPixels introduces a synchronization point and drivers are optimized to finish rendering the result to be returned by glReadPixels and to return from it as fast as possible. The main purpose of PBOs is to give the implementation some leeway when and how to finish rendering and the transfer (giving petter throughput, but actually increasing latency on glReadPixels).

Comment: @hemantc: Also you can do glReadPixels before buffer swap; however I strongly suggest to not "deadline" it, i.e. only start the transfer if you can assert that it will finish before the swap. Otherwise you might miss the deadline.

Comment: @datenwoof thanks I will try . What will be fastest way to capture  screen in binary or base32 format other than glReadPixels .